# How do I iterate though a variable in xsl within a template?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to set a variable up with nodes that I'd like to exclude from a document. My reasoning is I want it to be simple for non-coders to remove content from a xml document.

My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<document>
   <content name="location">New York</content>
   <content name="thing">Car</content>
   <content name="location">Baltimore</content>
</document>
```

My XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()>
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name='exclude'>
    <content name="location">New York</content>
    <content name="location">Baltimore</content>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="content">
<!--The problem is here. 
<xsl:for-each select="?iterate?">
  <xsl:if test="not(?If a match isn't found, copy?)">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
-->
</xsl:template>
```

After the transformation, the document should look like this:

```
<document>
       <content name="thing">Car</content>
 </document>
```

My main problem is I can't figure out how to juggle the node in the for-each and the node in the template to compare them.

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor do you need that to work with? The variable is a result tree fragment so it needs to be converted to a node-set first and the namespace of an extension function to do that can be processor specific (e.g. Microsoft Edge or IE or Microsoft's XslTransform need a different URI than the EXSLT most other processors support).

Comment: It's not Microsoft. It's actually built into the program I'm using...somewhere. I'll keep this in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is not how to iterate, but the fact that your variable is a result tree fragment, not a node-set. To avoid the issue, you can use an internal element instead of a variable:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:my="http://example.com/my"
extension-element-prefixes="my">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<my:exclude>
    <content name="location">New York</content>
    <content name="location">Baltimore</content>
</my:exclude>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- exclude listed nodes -->
<xsl:template match="content[document('')/xsl:stylesheet/my:exclude/content[. = current() and @name = current()/@name]]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

To use a variable as you started, you would have to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="exclude">
    <content name="location">New York</content>
    <content name="location">Baltimore</content>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="content">
    <xsl:if test="not(exsl:node-set($exclude)/content[. = current() and @name = current()/@name])">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The compare is probably too simple. The compare: (a) values of nodes are the same; (b) value of attribute `name` is the same; Depending on OP question, i think it might be "any/various" nodes to excluded from xml, e.g. `<content type="a">remove this as well</a>`.

Comment: Simple is ok. I have full control over the document. It makes sense, but when I test it the output isn't excluding. the line '<xsl:template match="content[document('')/xsl:stylesheet/my:exclude/content[. = current() and @name = current()/@name]]"/>'  It seems like the template doesn't match on anything. I'm using this test site: https://equallevel.com/punchout/xslt_tester.php

Comment: @JoshuaHedges I'm afraid this method will not work with most online testers (if any), due to their inability to resolve `document('')` to the current stylesheet.

Comment: Yea, you're probably right. The code seems solid. Is there a way for me to use a variable instead of a new node and namespace? It might sound weird, but this code is part of a huge xml search repository(Watson Explorer).

Comment: I am not sure what difference it makes, but see the addition to my post. Note also Martin Honnen's comment re some MS processors requiring a different namespace for the `node-set()` function.

Comment: In my case, I can't access the <xsl:stylesheet> node because it's built into the program somewhere, so I can't change it. This second version worked with an online tester too. Thanks a ton man!